# Changing output directory for a dll project

Tags: c++, configuration, project-properties

Trying to make the output of a dll project go into desired folders.

i have done this before, i don't understand why it doesn't work.

I have a dll wrapping up a lib. I need the output of the dll to be in `$(SolutionDir)\output\x86\$(Configuration)` instead of `$(SolutionDir)\output\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)`

So I edited the vcxproj file, added

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">    
    <OutDir>$(SolutionDir)\output\x86\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(SolutionDir)\output\x86\$(Configuration)\obj\$(ProjectName)\</IntDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">    
    <OutDir>$(SolutionDir)\output\x86\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(SolutionDir)\output\x86\$(Configuration)\obj\$(ProjectName)\</IntDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

In project Properties, I verified that the Output Directory and Intermediate Directory of the Win32 configurations, has changed to to `$(SolutionDir)\output\x86\$(Configuration)\`  and the respective intDir.

still, my output goes to Win32.

Looking at Command Line (in project properties) I still get the output going to Win32, and this is what really happens during build.

It worked for the lib, but it doesn't work for the dll.

Is there another place i must make this change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see - after testing a lot of options and searching every project text file, and not finding anything - that I must modify / replace the OutDir in the linker section, everywhere it appears, with the desired path.

I thought that would happen as soon as I set the OutDir...